# Hive: modify external table's location take too long

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, alluxio

Hive has two kinds of tables which are Managed and External Tables, for the difference, you can check [Managed. VS External Tables](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Managed+vs.+External+Tables#Managedvs.ExternalTables-RecoverPartitions(MSCKREPAIRTABLE)).

Currently, to move external database from `HDFS` to `Alluxio`, I need to modify external table's location to `alluxio://`.

The statement is something like: `alter table catalog_page set location "alluxio://node1:19998/user/root/tpcds/1000/catalog_returns"`

According to my understanding, it should be a simple metastore modification,however, for some tables modification, it will spend dozens of minutes. The database itself contains about 1TB data btw.

Is there anyway for me to accelerate the table alter process? If no, why it's so slow? Any comment is welcomed, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I found suggested way which is `metatool` under `$HIVE_HOME/bin`.

```
metatool -updateLocation <new-loc> <old-loc>      Update FS root location in the
                                          metastore to new location.Both
                                          new-loc and old-loc should be
                                          valid URIs with valid host names
                                          and schemes.When run with the
                                          dryRun option changes are
                                          displayed but are not persisted.
                                          When run with the
                                          serdepropKey/tablePropKey option
                                          updateLocation looks for the
                                          serde-prop-key/table-prop-key
                                          that is specified and updates
                                          its value if found.
```

By using this tool, the location modification is very fast. (maybe several seconds.)

Leave this thread here for anyone who might run into the same situation.

Comment: Do you still need to run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE ` after the updateLocation?

Comment: @apc999, honestly speaking, I didn't perform that operation. I confirmed the modification by two ways. 1, Check the external location in hive by 'desc formatted table_name". 2, Check the SDS table in Mysql metastore.

Comment: This one sounds intresting